# React App: Need advise on mapping json data into table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have to fetch data from an api and map it to table. This is my code. Would anyone please advise the map function? Thank you.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const MovieList = () => {

    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
    const fetchItems = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        `api endpoint url`
      )
      setMovies(result.data)
    }
    fetchItems()
  }, [])
    
  return (
    #omit codes for table heads 
          <tbody>
          {movies.map(movie => (
            <tr>
                <td>{movie.results.year}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
            </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
}
export default MovieList;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean _"advise the map function"_? `movie.results.year` doesn't make sense because, based on what you show, `movie.results` is an _array_.

Comment: provide actual json object here

Answer (score 1):

Update movies as

```
setMovies(result.data.results)
```

Then instead of

```
movies.map()
```

use

`movies[0].films.map(movie => {})`

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have a response that is `result` is an array of films (another array) in each year. So, the ugly way is just iterate carefully through these arrays, e.g:

```
      {movies.map((movie: any) => {
        movie.results.map((yearData: any) => (
          <tr>
            <td>{yearData.year}</td>
            {yearData.films.map((film: any) => (
              <Fragment>
                <td>{film['Detail URL']}</td>
                <td>{film.Film}</td>
                <td>{film['Producer(s)']}</td>
                <td>{...etc}</td>
              </Fragment>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ));
      })}
```

But if you can make the response better in backend, or perform some pre-processing of the result in the frontend, I suggest you to respond the films grouped by year, that would make everything easier. For example:

```json
[
  { 
    year: '2021',
    films: [{...}]
  },
  { 
    year: '1973',
    films: [{...}]
  },
  { 
    year: '1927 / 28 [A] (1st)',
    films: [{...}]
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks Luiz. I've been searching tutorials on how to process data like you suggested with node.js but I didn't find any good resources. There're tons of materials regarding node.js but indeed I can't find any useful ones. Would you please recommend how I can achieve the 2nd approach you suggested? Thank you.

Comment: One approach is using `_.groupBy` from Lodash's lib (https://lodash.com/). Could you edit the post with a example json?